# Populate form text input from PHP session - Simplify existing code

Tags: php

I have a simple HTML form that I am processing data from using PHP getting a text value from `myfield`.

I am trying to populate the text input if a value for it already exists in a PHP Session like this.

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['myfield'])) {

        $myfield = filter_var($_SESSION['myfield'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    } else {

        $myfield = ''

    }
    
    echo '<input type="text" value="' . $myfield . '">';
```

This seems a bit of a long-winded approach, is there a better way I can do this to cut down on bloat.

Is a ternary operator a good method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the shortest code I can came up:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="' . ($_SESSION['myfield'] ?? '') . '">';
```

More herein Null Coalescing Operator: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

For filter var you need to use the same operator, inside the function:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="' . (filter_var($_SESSION['myfield'] ?? '', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '') . '">';
```

or implement a function to filter multiples vars at once:

```
function filterMySessionVars() {
    $myVars = ['myfield1','myfield2',];
    foreach($myVars as $v) {
        $_SESSION[$v] = filter_var($_SESSION[$v] ?? '', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
}
filterMySessionVars();

echo '<input type="text" value="'.$_SESSION['myfield'].'">';
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO. But it's worth noting that the ?? operator need PHP 7.0 or later.

Comment: How can I handle the filter_var as well using this technique?

Comment: @fightstarr20 inside the function .. check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use a one line if, then embed it in the row
Maybe something like this should work:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="' . (isset($_SESSION['myfield'])) ? $_SESSION['myfield'] : '') . '">';
```